# Placing a sideways figure, with a sideways caption, underneath a (normal) subsection heading

Tags: rotating, sidewaysfigure

I have a figure that is wide (landscape orientation).  It is too wide to reasonably see in its native orientation.  So I have rotated it using the `sidewaysfigure` environment in the [`rotating`](https://ctan.org/pkg/rotating?lang=en) package.  However, when I do that, it places my figure on a separate page from my subsection heading.

[image: mwe]

How can I place a sideways figure -- with its associated sideways caption -- on the *same page* as a normally oriented subsection heading?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\section{My section}
\clearpage
\subsection{My subsection}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[!h]
  \centering
  \makebox[0.5\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}}
  \caption{This is a really, really, really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,   really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really, long caption.}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to use the entire page (except for the subsection) or as little space as possible?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'd like to use the entire page (except for the subsection).

Answer (score 2):

solution replacing `sidewaysfigure` with the `sideways` environment, and the `\ffigbox` command from `floatrow`:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[expansion=false, tracking=smallcaps, letterspace=40, final]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{floatrow} 

\begin{document}

\section{My section}
\clearpage
\subsection{My subsection}
\hfill\begin{sideways}
  \ffigbox[1.5\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}}
  {\caption{This is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long caption.}}
\end{sideways}\hfill\null

Some text. Some more text. Some more text.Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.Some more text. Some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How do I center it on the page? `\centering` does not seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: @Andrew: Oh! yes, I had overlooked this feature.  Please see the updated code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Zarko!

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a savebox to measure the height of the subsection, and creates a (rotated) minipage using the remaining space as the width (height).  `\rotatebox` comes with the graphicx package.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\begin{document}

\section{My section}
\clearpage% optional
\begin{figure}[p]
  \setbox0=\vbox{\subsection{My subsection}}% measure height
  \usebox0\par
  \vskip\textfloatsep\centering
  \rotatebox{90}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textheight-\ht0-\textfloatsep}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}% measure width
    \caption{This is a really, really, really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,   really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really, long caption.}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

---

This version overlaps the two.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\begin{document}

\section{My section}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]
  \setbox0=\vbox{\subsection{My subsection}}% measure height
  \usebox0\par\vskip-\ht0\vskip-\dp0% overlap
  \centering
  \rotatebox{90}{\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}% measure width
    \caption{This is a really, really, really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,   really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really,  really, long caption.}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```