# Display long table

Tags: tables, hyperref, longtable, tabularx, layout

Is there a way to display this wide table on an A4 page without using landscape?

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=3.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \tiny
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{18cm}{*{26}{l}}
        \hline
        Hostaddress &
        2 & 
        0 & 
        0 & 
        1 &
        : & 
        0 & 
        1 &
        9 &
        8 &
        : &
        0 &
        2 &
        0 &
        0 &
        : &
        1 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        : &
        : &
        C &
        C &
        C &
        C 
        \\ \hline
        binary &
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=0010,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=0001,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        : & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=0010,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=1001,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=1000,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        : &
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=0010,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        : &
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=0001,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        : &
        : &
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=1100,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=1100,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=1100,charsize = 5pt]{} & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=0.3cm, width=0.6cm, value=1100,charsize = 5pt]{} 
        \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sidewaystable from the rotating package.  Results are identical to using landscape (one plot per page) except the entire plot must fit on one page.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593199/placing-a-sideways-figure-with-a-sideways-caption-underneath-a-normal-subsec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In `tabularx` table at least one column has to be of `X` type.
- You can reduce separation between columns by setting `\tabcolsep` to for example 2pt.
- Two successive cells with `:` try to merge in one.

Considering above and use `\scriptsize` font size, you will get:

[image]

(gray lines indicate page border)

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=3.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \scriptsize
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X*{24}{c} @{}}
        \hline
        Hostaddress &
        2 &
        0 &
        0 &
        1 &
        : &
        0 &
        1 &
        9 &
        8 &
        : &
        0 &
        2 &
        0 &
        0 &
        : &
        1 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        :: &
        C &
        C &
        C &
        C
        \\ \hline
        binary &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=0010,charsize = 5pt]{}
        &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=0001,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        : & 
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=0010,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=1001,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=1000,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        : &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=0010,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        \TextField[name=2,,height=1em, width=2em, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        : &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=0001,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=0000,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        :: &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=1100,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=1100,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=1100,charsize = 5pt]{} &
        \TextField[name=2,height=1em, width=2em, value=1100,charsize = 5pt]{}
        \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that helped me a lot