How do I place a figure right after the Appendix heading/section without having it skip onto the next page?
Edit:
Here is the minimal working example (MWE):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\title{test appendix}
\author{john doe}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{appendices}
        \appendix
        \section[\appendixname~\thesection]{\label{appendix:01}}
        {
            \begin{sidewaysfigure}[hbtp!]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale = 1]{example-grid-100x100pt.jpg}
                \caption{abc}
                \label{fig:example}
            \end{sidewaysfigure}
        }
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}

Original post:
Here is the piece of code:
    \appendixtitles{no}
    %\vspace{0.01pt}
    \appendixstart
    
    \appendix
    \section[\appendixname~\thesection]{\label{appendix:01}}
    {   
        \begin{sidewaysfigure}[hbtp!]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale = 0.55]{images_figures/xyz.png}
            \caption{abc}
            \label{fig:xyz}
        \end{sidewaysfigure}
    }


I have tried using the specifier {hbtp!}, which did not work. I also tried {H} , which returned an error.

I have also tried using \vspace{} keyword as well as \clearpage and \newpage. But these didn't work instead, they only moved the figure to the next page while the Appendix A title remained in the preceding page.

I also observed that when the figure is in portrait style using the {figure} specifier instead of {sidewaysfigure}, and reduced in size, the figure aligns well and is positioned under the Appendix heading as it should. But I would like the landscape format as the figure is quite large.

I also tried reading the threads on similar subject (See making appendix for thesis)

Thank you in advance.



Please always probide a full but minimal example. I have no idea where \appendixstart comes from. Also, use an image from the mwe package, their names can be fopund here: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe, then everyone have that image.

Okay, my apologies. I'm fairly new to posting questions. Here is the full example code that you asked for in this link.
Would you like me to post the entire code here? It has a class definition in another folder and so I am not sure how I should go about posting it on here. Your suggestions are highly welcome. Thank you in advance.

@daleif: Please see minimal working example in the edited question above. Thank you in advance.

Possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593199/placing-a-sideways-figure-with-a-sideways-caption-underneath-a-normal-subsec

@JohnKormylo: Thank you! Your second solution from the link reference worked, i.e. using \begin{minipage}\end{minipage} environment. However, the first solution returned conflict errors due to floatrow and perhaps graphicx packages, among other issues. What's the next step? How do I close this thread since the issue has been resolved? Thanks, everyone!

Graphicx started use global registers ( see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685067/registers-0-9-policies?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C39.5468). Try using other register numbers, like working backwards from 9., or use \newsavebox to create a named savebox.

@JohnKormylo Interesting, thanks for shedding more light on this issue. Much appreciated!
